# Compare multiple conditions on two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an iteration/loop problem with multiple conditions to be met.

Table 1: HP_Checklist

[image: Table 1: HP_Checklist]

Table 2: Defek_Register

[image: Table 2: Defek_Register]

"Defek_Register" contains all the defects recorded whenever something has broken down. It has three columns of interest ("C" which contains the unique number of the defect is not applicable to this question):

1. equipment
2. wat is gecheck (what is checked)
3. defek_herstel (defect repaired)

Trying to determine: **In "HP_Checklist" what broke on which item of equipment?**

So look for the equipment in "Defek_Register" that is:

> E1 = vlookup(E1,defekregister!D:k)

if equipment is found, determine what has been checked for in J1

then see if it has been repaired "?"

if it has not been repaired (X) mark the block with an X (like "HP_Register" E11 = X ) and then search for the next case of E1.

I only need the entries that have not been repaired to be reflected in the checklist, so in this case the entries from "Defek_Register" K2, K12, K13 & K14 must be noted on "HP_Checklist".

Is there some way of checking multiple cells against multiple cells?

Secondly, I got the search to work but it won't iterate thru all the cells. For example I found the first HP_Cooker and then got stuck on that. I need to get all the defects reflected in the whole check sheet.

Here is the code I used for "HP_Checklist" (E10) `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(E$1,DefekRegister!$D:$K,8,0)="?","?","Defek"),"?")`

There are several check sheets but only one defect register.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you pnuts for the correction

Comment: I show column C because it contain the unique number of the system.

Comment: I show column C because it contain the unique number of the system.
You could insert the unique number or X into Hp_checklist. The problem is Defek_Register is ever changing, it start X and if repaired it change to a right mark (?) I need all the X to correspond into their respective sheets example HP_checklist,according to their machines and their applicable problem being checked example:In Hp_checklist,E1(hp_cooker) is checked against A11(Check all knifes and holeplates), do it exist, if exist is it broken(X) or repaired(?) if repaired search if it broke again (then question loop)

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly* you should be using a PivotTable:

[image: SO17990399 example]

(Where I have replaced `?` with (Blank) in the source).

Comment: Interesting perspective.The main idea is to print hp_ckecklist on a weekly basis to create a paper trail, and obviously see what is carried over to next week.I don't need to count it because it will always be only one "check gearbox oil" can only be done or not done.(except if that is the means of showing what is still not done).None the less I will give it a go, thanx